# How to create custom observable collection

Tags: javafx, observablecollection

I'd like to create an observable collection that should work like TransformationList reusing existing observable collections without actually storing data. I need collection that would implement kind of zip operation over several given collections. It is useful for creating tables based on aggregated data.

I plan to write custom listeners to both lists to update the combined list correspondingly. What I'm unaware off is how to use listener subscription architecture. What class should I extend to gain access to basic functionality of registering listeners, sending events to them, unsubscribing listeners?

Comment: Did you have a look at the FilteredList (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html)? Otherwise FXCollections factory class allows you to wrap existing Collection classes.

Comment: You also might want to look at the [source for `ObservableListBase`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/base/src/main/java/javafx/collections/ObservableListBase.java) to see how it is done there.